# Spring Security session-management setting and IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-security, session-timeout

I'm trying to add `<session-management>` in my Spring Security namespace configuration so that I can provide a different message than the login page when the session times out.  As soon as I add it to my configuration it starts throwing "IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed" when I access the app.

I'm using Spring Security 3 and Tomcat 6.  Here's my configuration:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/go.htm" access="ROLE_RESPONDENT" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/complete.htm" access="ROLE_RESPONDENT" />                          
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
                login-page="/login.htm" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true" 
                default-target-url="/go.htm"
    />      
    <anonymous/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout_message.htm"/>  
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.htm" />     

</http>
```

Everything works great until I add in the `<session-management>` line. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably hitting this bug:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1346

Try using the up-to-date version (3.0.2.RELEASE).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/taac/login">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</session-management>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe including the `auto-config="true"` attribute in the `<http>` tag helps, you might be missing some required filters or settings.